# Update a custom option value from cart page magento2

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to update the text field custom option programatically from the cart page. On the cart page I have a dropdown aside of each product. What I am trying to achieve is when I change the value of dropdown the respective value should be saved on that custom text field of that product.

**What I did till now?**

1. Created the text field custom option on the products.
2. Added the dropdown on the cart page

Can some one show how can I achieve this in Magento 2.